# Vue router redirect from a service?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Using vuejs 2 and the official vue-router.

How can I access the Router instance from a service that has not been given the instance?

---

We have an class that listens to a socket, on one particular event heard I need to use the vue-router to redirect to another page but I cannot see anywhere how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found is:

First initialize the app into the window obj.:

```
window.vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {App}
})
```

Now you access the router anywhere with ease:

```
window.vm.$route
```

or

```
window.vm.$router
```